# Mysql subquery advice

Tags: mysql, subquery

Hoping someone can advise on a subquery I'm trying to do. I'm still trying to get my head around on subqueries.

Here's a query I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT name (SELECT type AS User, count(*) As Number 
              from table 1 
              where event = 'answerall'
            ) from table 2
```

Running both queries on their own works fine, but can't get them working together.

I want to get the contents of the column name of table 2 and add them to table 1.

So ill have a query like this:

```
Name  User  Number
Jimmy  7001    7
```

Apologies I've tried:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    (SELECT 
            type AS Agent, COUNT(*) AS Number
        FROM
            queue_log
        WHERE
            event = 'OUTANSWER')
FROM
    agents_conf
```

and get the error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

queue_log table and agents_conf are not related to each other but are in the same database

Example of the queue_log table

```
uid  -  type        -  event
1    - Agent6001    - OUTANSWER
2    - Agent6002    - CONNECT
3    - Agent6001    - ABANDON 
4    - Agent5003    - OUTANSWER
```

Running this query works fine here:

```
SELECT type AS Agent, count(*) As Number from queue_log where event = 'OUTANSWER'
```

Agent.conf table:

```
agent_number   - name   
6001           - Jim    
6002           - James       
6003           - John
```

Running this query runs fine and provides me the list of all names

```
SELECT name from agents_conf
```

Comment: pity the above is didnt format correctly it should be

Name Jimmy
User 7001
Number 7

Comment: That's invalid syntax. `SELECT name (SELECT` is not proper syntax; at the very least it's missing a comma after `name` that would cause it not to run. It's either not your actual SQL, or you're getting an error you didn't bother to include in your question. Please [edit] to either include your actual code or to include the **exact** error message. You can also fix your code formatting while you're at it; use the `?` button on the toolbar to get help on how to do so. Also include some sample data from both tables;

Comment: `Running both queries on their own works fine.` this is simply untrue

Comment: Are the 2 tables related? If not then what is the logic of the query. If yes how? Edit your question with sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: mysql is saying that returnind two columns is not allowed. for such a subquery in that manner  but i would see the data that produces Jimmy  7001    7

Comment: You are expecting `Jimmy  7001    7` as a result. That 7001 is a value from the column agent_number of the table agents_conf. Why don't you select it like `select name, agent_number ...` but you select only name?

Comment: Most of my data is in the queue_log but I need to get name column from agent_conf included in my query. Maybe JOIN command will work better here. I was hoping to do this in a sub query

Comment: A join must be based on related columns of the 2 tables. I don't see any relation between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to S/O even though you appear to be getting pounded early on... don't sweat it though.   For the future, try to explain in simple English what you are trying to get, then show the supporting table structures and sample data of the respective tables.

Now, it looks like you are trying to get a count from the log file based on a given event ("OUTANSWER" in this case) based on each type.  The type actually represents a user (sounds very strange though).  Then, I need the person's name for each of the types (user).  -- Or at least something like this, and now on to your query.

One at a time. you somewhat presented, but changed the event where, using references of table 1 and table 2 which don't match the samples you provided.

With respect to the data, you have your queue_log table with the type all prefixed (in this sample set) with "Agent".  It this really accurate?  Because then in your agent table, you just have the apparent integer-based "ID" key.  If this is the case of the join, it is going to not work well if you are trying to compare the integer with a string that you have to strip off the "Agent" prefix, and are there other prefixes as well for other purposes?

So, given all these things that I hope you can provide clarification to, I will try to help.  First, the count per agent for a given thing...  In this case, I am going to pre-strip the "Agent" from the string of type field if it truly is a prefix for the agent.

```
select
      replace( ql.type, 'Agent', '' ) AgentID,
      count(*) AgentCount
   from
      queue_log ql
   where
      ql.Event = 'OUTANSWER'
   group by
      replace( ql.type, 'Agent', '' ) AgentID
```

This will return 2 rows.  One for each Outanswer record for the different respective agents, but at lease the AgentID column will be just 6001 and 5003 respectively, but still be a string.  Now, you want to get the name of the person, so you have to join to the agent table.  So, I will make the above query the primary select and assign it an alias so it can be JOINed to the agent table to get the name

```
select
      PreQuery.AgentID,
      PreQuery.AgentCount,
      a.Name
   from
      (select
            replace( ql.type, 'Agent', '' ) AgentID,
            count(*) AgentCount
         from
            queue_log ql
         where
            ql.Event = 'OUTANSWER'
         group by
            replace( ql.type, 'Agent', '' )) PreQuery
      JOIN Agent a
         on PreQuery.AgentID = a.agent_number
```

Now, if your queue_log is with the prefix of Agent + ID, I would strongly suggest breaking it up into two columns, such as

```
QueueID   KeySource  KeyID   Event
1         Agent      6001    OUTANSWER
2         Agent      6002    CONNECT
3         Agent      6001    ABANDON
4         Agent      5003    OUTANSWER
```

This way you can keep the KeyID as an integer and the source identify where it originates.  It will make things SO much easier in the future...

Comment: Ya I was getting pounded alright, thank you DRapp for the detailed response, it's been very helpful

Comment: @Patrickmysql, You are welcome, and if I am off on anything, let me know.  Your table structures should not ever merge things together like a Key ID as it just brings significant pain in the long run.  breaking in two columns as I have suggested is one way to retain the respective parts and their origin.